# d3.js build connections by using loop function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, web

I have build a connection by using d3. The codes show the data and method of connection:

```
var places = {
TYO: [139.76, 35.68],
BKK: [100.48, 13.75],
BER: [13.40, 52.52],
NYC: [-74.00, 40.71],
};
var connections = {
CONN1: [places.TYO, places.BKK],
CONN2: [places.BER, places.NYC],
};
...
svg.append("path")
   .datum({type: "LineString", coordinates: connections.CONN1})
   .attr("class", "route")
   .attr("d", path);
svg.append("path")
   .datum({type: "LineString", coordinates: connections.CONN2})
   .attr("class", "route")
   .attr("d", path);
```

You can see my codes, that I use the two identical methods to build two connections. That is not good to build more connections.

I am wondering, if there is a loop function to interpret the connections by using data "connections" directly? I mean, I could get information for data "connections" and use them directly to build connections.

I have thought some ways, such as `.datum({type: "LineString", function(d,i) {
return coordinates: connections[i];});`. But it does not work.

Could you please tell me some way to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally when you want to append many features in d3, you want to use an array not an object. With an array you can use a d3 enter selection which will then allow you to build as many features as you need (if sticking to an object, note that `connections[0]` is not what you are looking for, `connections["conn1"]` is).

Instead, use a data structure like:

```
var connections = [
[places.TYO, places.NYC],
[places.BKK, places.BER],
...
]
```

If you must have identifying or other properties for each datapoint use something like:

```
var connections = [
{points:[places.TYO, places.NYC],id: 1,...},
{points:[places.BKK, places.BER],id: 2,...},
...
]
```

For these set ups you can build your lines as follows:

```
paths = svg.selectAll(".connection")
    .data(connections)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class","connection")
    .attr('d', function(d) {
        return path ({ 
           type:"LineString",
           coordinates:  d 
        });
    })
```

[See here](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/591f072e6aa202f85fad2340767915bc). Or:

```
paths = svg.selectAll(".connection")
    .data(connections)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class","connection")
    .attr('d', function(d) {
        return path ({ 
           type:"LineString",
           coordinates:  d.points 
        });
    })
```

Alternatively, you can use a data set up like:

```
var connections = [
{target:"TYO", source:"NYC"},
{target:"BKK", source: "BER"},
...
]

paths = svg.selectAll(".connection")
    .data(connections)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class","connection")
    .attr('d', function(d) {
        return path ({ 
           type:"LineString",
           coordinates: [ places[d.source],places[d.target] ]
        });
    })
```

[See here](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/1b41b955eb6d212849a80b8ba454b20f).

---

If selecting elements that don't yet exist, using these lines

```
d3.select("...")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
```

will append a `path` for each item in the data array - this means that d3 generally avoids the use of for loops as the desired behavior is baked right into d3 itself.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your kind tutorial, I have learned much! I think I should not use the object as the connection variables. The array in the function to set is the best way, thanks again.